# playing video black rectangle

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mediaelement

I have to play a video demonstration when the user doesn't touch the mouse for few seconds.

```
<Window x:Class="IHM.Animation"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"  ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"  >
    <Grid>
        <MediaElement HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="video" Height="221" Margin="160,255,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="436" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

For the csharp  class, I have this:

```
 public partial class Animation : Window
 {
    public Animation()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
        player.Open(new Uri(@"airplane.mpg", UriKind.Relative));
        VideoDrawing drawing = new VideoDrawing {Rect = new Rect(0, 0, System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight, System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth)};
        player.Play();
        DrawingBrush brush = new DrawingBrush(drawing);
        Background = brush;
        MouseMove += (sender, args) =>
        {
            player.Stop();
           Close();
        };
    player.MediaEnded += (sender, args) => Close();
    }
}
```

But, I have a black rectangle without son or image.the uri  of the video is correct but it doesn't work.

Why is the video not working, how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you play your video in Windows Media Player? Does it work?

Comment: First of all, comment out that MouseMove handler and see if it is working.

Comment: nothing : a black screen is appears

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see you actually add the Visual to the UI. It's just created and run in the code-behind.

Updated Answer:

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();

public Window1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  player.Open(new Uri("airplane.mpg", UriKind.Relative));
  VideoDrawing drawing = new VideoDrawing {Rect = new Rect(0, 0, 800, 600), Player = player};
  player.Play();
  DrawingBrush brush = new DrawingBrush(drawing);
  Background = brush;
  player.MediaOpened += (sender, args) => MouseMove += OnMouseMove;
  player.MediaEnded += (sender, args) => {
    MouseMove -= OnMouseMove;
    Close();
  };
}

private void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs) {
  player.Stop();
  Close();
}
```

**Update:**

[Sample Download Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r5fkc4lv4vk2mqn/MyMediaPlayer.rar)

**Another Update:**

So the issue was also with having the `MouseMove` event firing too soon. Switching it to only capture `MouseEvents` after the `MediaOpened` event sorts that issue out.

Comment: @Lamloumi I've edited my answer with a link to the sample download you can download and have a look. It works fine for me. If the sample works fine for you, the issue is not something to do with the code but the actual file your trying to play. That could be a whole load of issues to start verifying if the URL is valid and sorts. Also remember in the code I've posted we pretty much render the Background of the Window with the Media `DrawingBrush` hence there is no need to have a `MediaElement` in xaml if doing this way.

Comment: thanks the problem is ,when i debbug the program, the handler `player.MediaEnded` didn't not waiting the end of the video

Comment: @Lamloumi I don't follow what you mean. Do you mean the Video is closing before it finishes? That might probably be because of the Mouse Moving which stops the player and closes the Window. In the sample i attached, If i hit play in Visual Studio and just take my hand off my mouse, I can see the video play once fully and then the Window closes which indicates the lambda for `MediaEnded` works correctly.

Comment: I mean that the event of the end of the video is called from the beginnig for the first video it is directly for the second you can listen to a son without image and it disappears rapidly!!!

Comment: Again I'm repeating this but "plssssssss" first try the attached sample and see if it on your machine is showing the same behavior. You got a problem and to fix it you need to start small. The biggest issue in such cases is not actually the code but the file's you got. For all we know the video you have is corrupt or only 1 second long which would then be valid logic to invoke the `MediaEnded` event the very second play is called. Nothing you described yet I've been able to reproduce in the sample. So step 1 is first try it and see if your problems still exist in the demo.

Comment: please understood me : i am testing Your code sample.for the video i tried `airplane.mpg` and the other videos are not corrupt. The result: nothing is appears : the event mediaEnded called in the beginning

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29855/discussion-between-lamloumi-and-viv)